# How to allow the desktop application to access the MySQL DB on a Microsoft server?

Tags: java, mysql, database, server, database-connection

I’m building a desktop application using Java and a MySQL Database.

The MySQL Database is supposed to be connected within the desktop application, is stored on the MySQL server on the Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

I installed the desktop application on two different PCs on the same Network.

*(So the DB on the server and the app on the Clients PCs)*

**The problem is:**
The desktop application is not working, since the clients PCs can’t access the MySQL DB.

**My Questions are:**

- How do I allow the desktop application on a client PC to access the
  MySQL DB  on a server?
- Do I need to change the code that is supposed
  to connect to the Database on the Microsoft Server?

  ```
  public static Connection Connerdb()
  {
      try
      {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/TestDB",root, " " );
          return con;
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
          return null;
      }   
  }
  ```

Comment: Silly question I'm sure, but does your configuration work on any other clients besides the 2 you tried? Does the user that is trying to connect to the MySQL have "create session" privileges?

Comment: Actually i haven't tried on other PCs, but i thinks it won't work. no the user that is trying to connect to the MySQL doesn't  have "create session" privileges. How can i give it?

Comment: See @MartinStraus answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have "localhost" in the JDBC URL. You should use the IP address or the DNS name of the MySQL host.

Comment: Good catch, I was thinking too big!

Comment: Thanks for help. But when i tried to run the desktop application on a client PC, this error appeared ( java.sql.SQLException:null, message from server:"Host 'pc1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" )

Comment: That looks more like a MySQL configuration issue than a client problem. In MySQL, part if the identification of a user is the host from which it connects. Usually, you'll have users named something like myuser@%, the "%" meaning "any host". So, that user will be able to connect from any host. But if the user is named "myuser@localhost", it will only be allowed to connect from the _same host in which MySQL is running_, and not from any remote client (which is your case). You should check this setup in your MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, the user is root@localhost. But how to configure the MySQL server (Sorry I'm newbie) ?